# MYSQL Distict value from many tables with smallerst value

Tags: mysql, sql, database, select

I have three tables with products:

table1: producer_code, price, company

table2: producer_code, price, company

table3: producer_code, price, company

Now I want to list products (distinct from all table) this I can do:

```
select distinct producer_code, price, company
from (
    select producer_code, price, company FROM table1
    union all
    select producer_code, price, company FROM table2
    union
    select producer_code, price, company FROM table3
) tmp_table
```

but **how to list only cheapest products?** Example: if the same product will be in three tables I would like to have it listen only one time but from the cheapest source (company column).
Should I use union or join?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select distinct producer_code, min(price), company
from (
    select producer_code, price, company FROM table1
    union all
    select producer_code, price, company FROM table2
    union all
    select producer_code, price, company FROM table3
) tmp_table
group by producer_code,company
```

Comment: distinct here is unnecessary, since you already have a group by.

Answer (score 1):

using `min` can get the smallest value.

I think you might use `UNION ALL`

```
select producer_code, MIN(price), company
from (
    select producer_code, price, company FROM table1
    union all
    select producer_code, price, company FROM table2
    union all
    select producer_code, price, company FROM table3
) tmp_table
GROUP BY producer_code,company
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get it as below usinf `Min`:

```
select producer_code, Min(price), company
from (
    select producer_code, price, company FROM table1
    union all
    select producer_code, price, company FROM table2
    union
    select producer_code, price, company FROM table3
) tmp_table
group by tmp_table.producer_code, tmp_table.company
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the OP needs cheapest price from variety of the companies and that too stored on multiple tables.

**Ex Schema:**

```
create table table1(producer_code varchar(50), price decimal(18,2), company varchar(100));
create table table2(producer_code varchar(50), price decimal(18,2), company varchar(100));
create table table3(producer_code varchar(50), price decimal(18,2), company varchar(100));

insert into table1
select 'ITEM001', 45, 'Company A' 
UNION ALL
select 'ITEM002', 200, 'Company B'
UNION ALL
select 'ITEM003', 150, 'Company B';

insert into table2
select 'ITEM001', 50, 'Company B'
UNION ALL
select 'ITEM002', 300, 'Company C'
UNION ALL
select 'ITEM003', 55, 'Company D';

insert into table3
select 'ITEM001', 190, 'Company F'
UNION ALL
select 'ITEM002', 78, 'Company G'
UNION ALL
select 'ITEM003', 100, 'Company A';
```

We need to Join 2 sets here. One is actual combined set A and another is a set with producer_code and  minimum price.

```
select 
A.* from 
(
SELECT * FROM table1
UNION 
SELECT * FROM table2
UNION 
SELECT * FROM table3
)A
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT producer_code, min(price) AS price FROM (
    SELECT * FROM table1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT * FROM table2
    UNION ALL
    SELECT * FROM table3
    )B
    GROUP BY producer_code
)CHEAP ON A.producer_code = CHEAP.producer_code AND A.price = CHEAP.price;
```

**Result :**

```
+---------------+---------+-------------+
| producer_code |  price  |   company   |
+---------------+---------+-------------+
| 'ITEM001'     | '45.00' | 'Company A' |
| 'ITEM003'     | '55.00' | 'Company D' |
| 'ITEM002'     | '78.00' | 'Company G' |
+---------------+---------+-------------+
```

Comment: Thank you. This is the interested solution, but the other answers also work and are simpler